# Method not Allowed error on Ajax Post request (500 error) Laravel Framework

Tags: ajax, laravel, ajax-request

I am working on a Post Ajax request Function. Where the function takes some data and send it through an enabled CSRF_token post Request to a controller and then after evaluations on controller a message sent back to the view. but it seems i miss a small thing in my code.

My controller

```
 public function PostMessage(Request $request){

    $message=$request->someData;  //getting data from request variable 
    return response()->json($message);
}
```

My jquery Ajax request function

```
 $('.SendAjaxPostRequest').on('click', function() {
       var value=$('.MessageHolder').val();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url:'{{route('SVCate')}}', //SVCate is my route to the controller
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {_token:token,'someData':value,} 
            // #token gets it's value from a local view javaScrip Variable
        })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
    });
```

My route function

```
    Route::post('SendMessage','NessageController@PostMessage')->name('SVCate');
```

Comment: Try clearing the route cache `php artisan route:clear` https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#route-caching

Comment: thank you linktoahref, no , i dont have version problem and already tested the type but not working.

Comment: how do you get token value?

Comment: <scrip type="text/javascript">
 
var token='{{Session::token()}}';
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Check your apostrophes in the `url`. You are ending the string and beginning the string around `SVCate` change it to `url:"{{route('SVCate')}}"` to make sure that `SVCate` stays a string and does not break your string.

Comment: thank you Teun,
no the string get to the controller, if i change the methods of POST all to GET so this code has no error but only it's not working with POST.